# Python ‘entry’ text make readable only

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the next line of code to create entry text inputs in python:

```
globals()[f"dv_{key}_{subkey}"] = tk.Entry(self.root, width=250)
```

That text create input texts to enter data as shown in photo:

[image]

I want to make only readable then I entered the command as this:

```
globals()[f"dv_{key}_{subkey}"] = tk.Entry(self.root, width=250, state='disabled')
```

Of course it does the job so you can’t input text hat is what I want, the problem is the text they have disappear as shown in photo:

[image]

How can i make to make readable only but that they show the real values the had before i entered the `state='disabled'`?

Here is code to read de JSOn file:

```
import json
import tkinter as tk

class JsonEditor:
    def __init__(self, root, filename):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("JSON Editor")
        self.json_data = {}
        self.textboxes = []
        self.filename = filename
        self.read_file()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # create menu bar
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.root)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_file)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)

        # create textboxes for JSON keys and values
        row = 0
        for key, value in self.json_data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                label = tk.Label(self.root, text=key)
                label.grid(row=row, column=0)
                row += 1
                for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
                    sublabel = tk.Label(self.root, text=subkey)
                    sublabel.grid(row=row, column=1)
                    subtextbox = tk.Entry(self.root, width=50)
                    subtextbox.insert(0, subvalue)
                    subtextbox.grid(row=row, column=2)
                    self.textboxes.append((key, subkey, subtextbox))
                    row += 1
            else:
                label = tk.Label(self.root, text=key)
                label.grid(row=row, column=0)
                textbox = tk.Entry(self.root, width=50)
                textbox.insert(0, value)
                textbox.grid(row=row, column=1)
                self.textboxes.append((key, textbox))
                row += 1

        # create submit button
        submit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=self.save_file)
        submit_button.grid(row=row, column=1)

    def read_file(self):
        with open(self.filename, "r") as f:
            self.json_data = json.load(f)

    def save_file(self):
        for item in self.textboxes:
            if len(item) == 2:
                key, textbox = item
                self.json_data[key] = textbox.get()
            elif len(item) == 3:
                key, subkey, subtextbox = item
                self.json_data[key][subkey] = subtextbox.get()
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            json.dump(self.json_data, f)

root = tk.Tk()

# set the display resolution
root.geometry("800x600")

# set the JSON file path
filename = "C:/orderprepare.json"

# create the editor GUI
editor = JsonEditor(root, filename)

# start the GUI main loop
root.mainloop()
```

The script reads any JSON file with any values but anyway I attach and example of JSON file:

```
{
    "ShipTo": {
        "CustomerName1": "test test",
        "CustomerName2": "test test",
        "Phone": "000-000-0000dfswerwer",
        "Address1": "test test",
        "Address2": "dfewrwer",
        "City": "Tazewellddsewrer",
        "StateOrProvince": "TNdsfsewr",
        "PostalCode": "82823",
        "Country": "USA"
    },
    "BillTo": {
        "CustomerName1": "test2 test2",
        "CustomerName2": "test2 test2",
        "Address1": "test test",
        "Address2": "dfewrwer",
        "City": "anywhere",
        "StateOrProvince": "TNdsfsewr",
        "PostalCode": "84747",
        "Country": "USA"
    },
    "ItemList": [
        {
            "ItemNumber": "itemxxxx111",
            "BuyerPartNumber": "partxxx1111",
            "Quantity": "7",
            "UnitPrice": "809"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Please only add the tag for the version you are using (if that is necessary at all), not for the version you are not using.

Comment: I’m using python 3.10

Comment: I attached a source code of this in the main question

Comment: Don't treat the global namespace like a dict. Create your own explicit dict to store `Entry` and other interface objects.

Comment: Please make sure we can run your code. This code depends on a json file that we do not have. Please consider hard-coding some data instead of requiring a separate file. Unless the problem is specifically caused by using JSON, it would be better to create a smaller example that doesn't rely on the json module at all.

Comment: The code  recognizes any JSON file with any values. Try and you will see. Any JSON file will be displayed in the GUI. Left Side the keys and the right side the subkeys. Ay way I entered in the man question one example.

Comment: When I run your code and change the state to `readonly` or `disabled` after inserting the data in the widget, the data remains visible. Please provide an example that illustrates the problem you're. having with the data becoming invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert the data before setting the state, otherwise the state of "readonly" or "disabled" will prevent you from inserting the data.

```
...
for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
    ...
    subtextbox = tk.Entry(self.root, width=50)
    subtextbox.insert(0, subvalue)
    subtextbox.configure(state="disabled")
    ...
```

Comment: Exactly that makes the job. The ‘subtextbox.configure(state="disabled")’ modes the trick. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "state" of the Entry widget to "readonly" instead of "disabled". This will make the widget read-only, but still display its value.

Here's an updated code example:

```
globals()[f"dv_{key}_{subkey}"] = tk.Entry(self.root, width=250, state='readonly')
```

With this change, the Entry widget will still display its value, but the user won't be able to edit it.

Comment: Oh is more interesting readonly. However, it continues doing the same. It removes the write function but as shown in photo the real values were there disappear. I just see the effect of readonly not input text availability but I just blank disabled boxes